# Select node from XML

Tags: c#, asp.net

I new to xml and a litlle confused.

I have next xml

```
<Data>
    <seo>
        <Title>
            <ID>Site_Title</ID>
            <name>A Media</name>
        </Title>

        <Keywords>
            <ID>Keywords</ID>
            <name>A, Media, keywords</name>
        </Keywords>

        <Site_Description>
            <ID>Site_Description</ID>
            <name>A Media site description</name>
        </Site_Description>
    </seo>

    <main_slider>
        <slider1>
            <id></id>
            <image_url></image_url>
            <text></text>
            <btn_text></btn_text>
            <btn_link></btn_link>
        </slider1>

        <slider2>
            <id></id>
            <image_url></image_url>
            <text></text>
            <btn_text></btn_text>
            <btn_link></btn_link>
        </slider2>

        <slider3>
            <id></id>
            <image_url></image_url>
            <text></text>
            <btn_text></btn_text>
            <btn_link></btn_link>
        </slider3>

        <slider4>
            <id></id>
            <image_url></image_url>
            <text></text>
            <btn_text></btn_text>
            <btn_link></btn_link>
        </slider4>

        <slider5>
            <id></id>
            <image_url></image_url>
            <text></text>
            <btn_text></btn_text>
            <btn_link></btn_link>
        </slider5>

    </main_slider>

</Data>
```

### Masterpage.cs

```
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

   doc.Load(Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data/A_data.xml"));
```

Ok, how from here i can continue? lets say i have next code:

```
    Page.Title = title_str; // Title set
    Page.MetaDescription = description; // Description set
    Page.MetaKeywords = keywords; // Keywords set
```

How i get the title > name node from xml? and keywords > name and so on...

It must done only via "foreach" ? anyway, how?

Comment: -1 for no research effort. There are *so* many tutorials available about how to get data from XML files.

Comment: I'd recommend using XDocument (LINQ To Xml) if you're just starting.  It's better.

Comment: After 7 days of reasearch , how i started? i confused, so thanks for the -1.

Comment: I don't see any research here. Check out these questions and their answers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+select+node+from+XmlDocument They already should get you much further.

Comment: You dont see, i did reaserched and most of answers was with foreach that i dont want,but @lazyberezovsky helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Linq to Xml:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data/A_data.xml");
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
var seo = xdoc.Root.Element("seo");
Page.Title = (string)seo.Element("Title").Element("name");
Page.MetaDescription = (string)seo.Element("Site_Description").Element("name");
Page.MetaKeywords = (string)seo.Element("Keywords").Element("name");
// etc
```

Also I suggest you to take a look on [LINQ to XML Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688087.aspx) to understand how to use it in future.

You can also use xpath (it's better option, if some some element could be missing):

```
Page.Title = (string)xdoc.XPathSelectElement("Data/seo/Title/name");
```

Comment: Quick and right, thank you, exact what i searched for and from some reason cant find. in 8 minutes will set as right answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
doc.Root.Element("seo").Element("Title").Element("name").Value;
doc.Root.Element("seo").Element("Keywords").Element("name").Value;
doc.Root.Element("seo").Element("Site_Description").Element("name").Value;
```

If you want to interate into sliders, its good to use a foreach, but as you are asking for the seo values, which only appear once in the xml, its better to select the nodes and value directly

Comment: Thanks :) good answer. Yeah, mistakenlly i added the slider to my example here.