# select XML item by value (GPS)

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone application where I want to find the current air pollution but there is no API in England so I am trying to extract a GPS value from an XML item so I can then find the closest XML item to the phones GPS.

XML

http://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/assets/rss/current_site_levels.xml

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Did you forgot to add the code for accessing/selecting node from that xml?

Comment: Okay, so that's a pretty ugly XML format, but just about feasible... how far have you got? Have you extracted the data from the XML to something more useful, to start with?

Comment: Sorry I am a noob to this site

Comment: Can [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590965/select-node-from-xml) be of help?

Comment: I really do not know where to start but am willing to put in the work to do this. Even if someone could point me in the right direction?

Comment: This might get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487167(v=vs.105).aspx